# $sce.trustAsHtml vs. ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs

Why can't I do this:

```
<div>{{data | htmlfilterexample}}</div>
```

When, inside the filter, I am returning:

```
return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
```

Using `<div ng-bind-html="data | htmlfilterexample"></div>` works regardless if the filter returns `input` or `$sce.trustAsHtml(input)`.

I was under the impression that `$sce` makes HTML trustworth and `ng-bind-html` isn't needed for output returned by that method.

Thanks.

Comment: I am confused, you say you _cannot_ do `<div>{{data | htmlfilterexample}}</div>` and then later that it works regardless of whether you return `input` or `$sce.trustAsHtml(input)`?

Comment: Yeah, the first is inside `{{}}` the second is inside `ng-bind-html`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`$sce.trustAsHtml()` produces a string that is safe to use with `ng-bind-html`.  Were you to not use that function on the string then `ng-bind-html` would yield the error:  [`$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.`  So **$sce doesn't get rid of the need for `ng-bind-html` rather it makes the string it processes safe to use with it.**

The specific issue you're running into lies in the difference between `ng-bind` and `ng-bind-html`

Using `{{}}` is the equivalent of `ng-bind`.  So, looking at the `ng-bind` source code ([ng-bind-* source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d7ed885984d58d344350ae267f51e8096bb6bea6/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js)) we see that it uses this:

```
element.text(value == undefined ? '' : value);
```

while `ng-bind-html`, amongst other things, does the following:

```
var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '');
```

The key takeaway being that the `ng-bind` use of **.text** (http://api.jquery.com/text/) results in the text representation of the string being displayed (ignoring whether it's HTML trustworthy).

While the `ng-bind-html` use of **.html** (http://api.jquery.com/html/) **results in the html interpreted version** (if declared safe by `getTrustedHtml()`)

Comment: Saying "$sce.trustAsHtml() produces a string that is safe to use with ng-bind-html" seems catastrophically misleading and incorrect. It yields a proxy for *sanitisation bypass*, and the result could be completely *unsafe* to use with ng-bind-html. Ordinarily if an expression used with ng-bind-html evaluated to `X<script>alert('foo')</script>X`, the script element would be removed by `$sanitize` leaving `XX`, however if the value was derived via trustAsHtml, the script tags would remain. This is its purpose, enabling injection of arbitrary HTML when needed, but it is not making anything "safe".