# HTML tag in scope of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I need to put a `<br />` tag in $scope.myText in a controller, how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `$sce.trustAsHtml("<br />")` should work.

`$sce.trustAsHtml()` returns a string that is safe to use with `ng-bind-html`. You can read more about it here

[$sce.trustAsHtml vs. ng-bind-html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20256564/1959948)